# Headset jack not working even when using sound > test

Tags: spdif

I have ubuntu 13.04 and the sound has never worked in this OS/version for the headset jack. It does work with normal speakers.

The same PC was windows before and it was working ok so no hardware problem
It does work with USB headphone

I tried killing pulseaudio program
I tried going to Sound > Select output device > test  > nothing sounds from the headset 
It has following output devices: 
- Digital output (S/PDIF)  > No sound.. 
- Headphones > Sound comes from speaker
- Analog output/Built-in > Sound comes from speaker
- Analog output/C-media USB  > USB sound ok.

Tried opening alsamixer(v1.0.25) and setting high sound volume for all devices, including headphones.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to try to make `alsa` reload:

```
  sudo alsa force-reload
```

Then you'll want to reboot.

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio alsa-base 
 sudo apt-get install pulseaudio alsa-base
```

Then `sudo alsa force-reload` again.
Remember to reboot.

If even that doesn't work, go into speech-dispatcher:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

And change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`. Reboot. 
If all else fails, you may have to reinstall Ubuntu and try these commands again (this is what I had to do)